# Why is there an extra (4) in the output of align?

Tags: equations, align, numbering, amsmath, output

```
\documentclass {article}  

\usepackage {amsmath}  
\usepackage {amssymb}  


\begin {document}  

With `` align* ''  ( you require manual numbering) :-  

\begin {align*}  
\alpha &= \beta + \gamma                                      \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (1) \\  
\alpha + \beta &= \frac {\gamma}{\delta}   + \delta \int \mu d\mu         \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (2) \\  
\alpha + \beta\mu &= \gamma\delta   \ \   \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (3) \\
\end {align*}\\  
\\  
\\  
\\  
\\  
With ``align'' (you get automatic numbering) :-  

\begin {align}  
\alpha &= \beta + \gamma \\  
\alpha + \beta &= \frac {\gamma}{\delta}   + \delta \int \mu d\mu  \\  
\alpha + \beta\mu &= \gamma\delta\\  
\end {align}\\  
\end {document}
```

Comment: as commented on your previous question, all the `\\ ` here are wrong, why do you still have them?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle    I add them to get extra spacing between the lines Sir...

Comment: no they do not add space they force empty lines they are the completely wrong way to use latex. LaTeX has no way of making reasonable page breaks if you use `\\ ` in this way. The vertical space aroud math displays is a document level parameter that can be set by the document class or in the preamble (`\abovedisplayskip`) you should nver need to space it in the  document and certainly never with `\\ ` (which does not add space at all)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Can you please suggest anything else Sir, in order to get a gap of few blank lines wherever desired, in the output ? I'm a newbie... still learning to use the Latex...

Comment: if you want vertical spaces between paragraphs add `\usepackage{parskip}` to your document and just leave a blank line in the source between paragraphs.

Comment: also of course never number equations with `\quad\quad(2}` you can number by hand by using `\tag{2}`   delete all the `\quad`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle   Thank you Sir for your helpful suggestions. I'll certainly try to run them in my code on Latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle    It worked. Thank you Sir !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the last `\\` inside `align` (the one after `\gamma\delta`).

Comment: Got it.   Thank you, Sir !     It solved the problem  .